# Get config value in XML layout

Tags: magento2, header, values

I create config value in system.xml that contain src of a script tag
how can i call this value in view\frontend\layout\default.xml file in head tag

Answer (score 0):

You have to create custom block and insert in default.xml like this:

```
<referenceBlock name="head.components">
    <block class="\Test\Test\Block\TestBlock" name="test" template="Test_Test::template.phtml" before="-" />
</referenceBlock>
```

And your `Test\Test\Block\TestBlock` can look like this:

```
class TestBlock extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    private \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    public function getScriptSrcConfig(): string
    {
        return $this->scopeConfig->getValue('path/to-your/config');
    }
}
```

and in templtate you just use

```
<?= /** @noEscape */ $block->getScriptSrcConfig() ?>
```

P.S. There is a better way from technical perspective, but it's more difficult - https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/view-models.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is there a way to do it with helper like this https://www.kishansavaliya.com/magento2/get--system-xml-config-value-in-layout-xml.html

Comment: yes, it's possible, you can pass some helper method which gets config into block arguments, but anyway it would be required to execute block in template

Answer (score 0):

First create a Helper class and call get the config value inside the helper. use that helper value in template file.
you can directly call from helper to phtml file or from helper -> block-> phtml file
[ there are different ways too but I used it most of the time]
refer this link for details of code.
https://vrajeshpatel.in/2021/05/22/how-to-create-system-xml-configuration-and-get-data-from-system-configuration-in-magento-2/